# Why only outdated version of NPM is available on Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using a Debian/Ubuntu based distribution (specifically, AWS Ubuntu 16.04) and trying to install NPM through `apt-get`.

My Angular 2 application needs a higher version than 3.9.x of NPM, but the default version which is getting installed is 3.5.2 using `sudo apt-get install npm` on AWS Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to update NPM, but it's not getting upgraded to 4.6.1 (latest) from 3.5.2.

How do I install/update NPM so that I've got the latest version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting version 3.5.2 of npm, because that's the version in the [repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/web/npm). Debian and Ubuntu are typically *terrible* at keeping up with Node and npm's fast rate of development, so you'll often find the packages are out of date, and aren't much use to you.

Some Debian distributions (e.g. Jessie) only have npm [v1.4.21](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/npm/download), which is even more out of date. Incidentally, Debian Jessie is the version upon which Raspbian Jessie, the RPi distribution, is based.

Instead, follow [the instructions given on the Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions):

> Node.js is available from the NodeSource Debian and Ubuntu binary distributions repository (formerly Chris Lea's Launchpad PPA). Support for this repository, along with its scripts, can be found on GitHub at nodesource/distributions.
>
> NOTE: If you are using Ubuntu Precise or Debian Wheezy, you might want to read about running Node.js >= 6.x on older distros.
>
> ```
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```
>
> Alternatively, for Node.js v7:
>
> ```
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
> sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
> ```

The `nodejs` package provided by NodeSource includes npm. Simply install that, and you'll be ready to go with the latest version.

Comment: I don't think they are terrible at updating every package.  I wonder if the node and v8 code is easy to audit etc..

Comment: thanks, i used `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x`

Answer (score 17):

type 'hash -r' on your server bash.

Then check your 'npm -v' again

Comment: Thank you Sir, I for one was going insane

Comment: This was it. Totally going insane.

Comment: This worked, however do you have an explication as to why? It updated the symbolic link in /usr/local/bin/npm to ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js but how did it know to do so, or what was wrong?

Answer (score 7):

**Upgrade npm:**

```
$ sudo npm install -g npm@latest

$ reboot

$ npm -v
```

---

**Complete installation:**

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs

$ sudo apt install npm

$ npm -v
```

npm version: 3.5.2

Then upgrade:

```
$ npm install -g npm@latest

$ reboot

$ npm -v
```

Comment: 'hash -r' in your shell is enough instead of a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo npm install -g npm`

Was what worked for me, I then needed the answer provided by @StefanBob

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Comment: wow this works. can you explain the `n` and why force `cache clean` and `n stable` does the trick??

Answer (score 0):

I've read this answer and it helped me on this issue:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036278/npm-is-incorrect-version-on-latest-ubuntu-18-04-installation

I hope it helps you aswell.

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
(...apt installation of npm was successful...)
$ npm -v
3.5.2
$ command -v npm
/usr/bin/npm
$ sudo npm install -g npm
(...npm installation of npm was successful...so far, so good)
```

After that, just restart the bash or follow krubo's steps.

Answer (score 0):

[@Nyakwar Dayo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60892426/4739826)'s solution worked for me.

> ```
> sudo npm cache clean -f
> sudo npm install -g n
> sudo n stable
> ```

But the nodejs package was installed at a different path and I manually deleted the old package (in `/usr/bin/`) and added a symlink to point to the new one (in `/usr/local/bin`).

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/node /usr/bin/node
```

This is the initial printouts from running the commands. The `npm` version updates from `5.8.0` to `8.1.2`. But the `nodejs` version stayed at `10.24.0` even after reboot with `hash -r`.

[image: bash-ss]