# Trying to install npm on Raspberry Pi Error

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, electron

I am working on a simple smart mirror project with javascript and electron. I was able to get the software working on my laptop but when I moved it to the raspberry pi I am having issues installing npm. After entering "npm install" I get this:

```
npm WARN package.json bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'types/jquery' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'smart-mirror-server'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.24-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/Desktop/smart-connected-mirror-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/Desktop/smart-connected-mirror-master/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have tried 
     sudo apt-get update 
as well as 
     sudo apt-get upgrade

Any ideas what to do? Thanks!

EDIT:

I updated the node.js to a more current version and now it installed without error. However, when I typed in the command

```
 npm start
```

I get this:

```
 sh: 1: electron: Permission denied

 npm ERR! Linux 4.9.24-v7+
 npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
 npm ERR! node v7.10.0
 npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 126
 npm ERR! smart-mirror-server@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
 npm ERR! Exit status 126
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the smart-mirror-server@1.0.0 start script 'electron      .'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm      installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the smart-mirror-  server package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     electron .
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
 npm ERR!     npm bugs smart-mirror-server
 npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls smart-mirror-server 
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2017-05-29T03_33_22_466Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The Node.js version that you're using is very old. Try installing a more recent version (v6, for instance). Instructions can be found here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I only install version 3.5.2 of NPM on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095985/why-can-i-only-install-version-3-5-2-of-npm-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Hi @robertklep I updated node.js and now it has installed properly. But after typing in the command for npm start I am getting a new error. I have edited the original post to show this error. I know these are probably simple questions but, I am unfamiliar with all this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [issue](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/issues/145)? Electron works only on RaspberryPi 2/3 what version are you using?
Also have you run `npm install` before actually run the app? Sometimes when copying `node_modules` from OS to OS the executable permissions get very confused.
You can try a fresh install with: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`